# sql issue with having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having, ora-00979

Im trying to find query each model with their most used ram configuration.

Table:

```
PC (code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
```

So far, I was able to list every model with every ram config and number of times the ram config has been used.

```
select model, ram, max(config)
  from (select model,ram,count(ram) as config
          from pc 
         group by model, ram)
 group by model, ram
```

Output:

```
MODEL   RAM  MAX(CONFIG)
------- ---- -----------
1232    64   2
1232    32   2
1233    128  3
1121    128  3
1233    64   1
1260    32   1
```

I face problems when I try to have model listed with its most used ram.

```
select model, ram
  from (select model, ram, count(ram) as config
          from pc 
         group by model, ram)
 group by model
having config = max(config);


Error : ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with x as 
(select model,ram,count(ram) as config
from pc 
group by model,ram)
, y as 
(select model, max(config) as mxconfig from x group by model)
select x.model, x.ram --choose max(x.ram) or min(x.ram) in case of a tie and group by x.model
from x join y on x.model = y.model and x.config = y.mxconfig
```

This solution uses `cte` to achieve what you need. If you need to get either `max` or `min` ram when there is a tie for config, you should have one more `group by` on model.

Comment: gives error:  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: same error . im executing "select model, max(ram)
from (select model,ram,count(ram) as config
from pc 
group by model,ram) t
group by model
having config = (select max(config) from t)"

Comment: modified it again.. try this.

Comment: Wow. This works.Thanks a lot vkp !!! Can you please give a short summary of what this query does pls?

Comment: the first `cte` x is same as your query. The second `cte` uses the results of x and does more manipulation. Finally, you use x and y like tables, join them and select what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT model,ram FROM (SELECT model,ram,count(ram) AS config
FROM pc 
GROUP BY model,ram)
WHERE config=max(config)
```

The records should already be grouped by your sub query

Comment: gives error :  ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use window functions:

```
select model, ram
from (select model, ram,
             row_number() over (partition by model order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from pc 
      group by model, ram
     ) mr
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This works. But what will happen when 2 ram configs have been used equal number of times? whiich one will be displayed?

Comment: @zoro . . . One will be chosen arbitrarily.  If you want both, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.